# Is there a cost to jQuerying an existing jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, benchmarking

I'm wondering whether lazily doing `$( something )` without first checking whether `something` is already a jQuery instance has any performance downsides?

The use case I'm thinking of is a function like the following:

```
function foo( element ){
  var $element = $( element );
  // do something with $element...
}
```

If you pass a jQuery instance to that function, are you re-wrapping a jQuery instance with another jQuery instance? And does that have any performance implications (say, over many iterations)?

```
foo( $( "#somediv" ) );
```

Looking at the source code (v 2.1.4 as of this question), we see `jQuery.fn.init` checking the selector that's passed to it, and if it's not a string, a DOM element or a function, then we just pass it through `jQuery.makeArray` and return the result.

So there doesn't appear to be any explicit checking within the jQuery "constructor" that short-circuits if the selector is already a jQuery instance. But does it really matter?

`makeArray` uses `merge` and/or `push`, so there's a bit of extra processing, but is it significant?

Comment: If you're uncertain, I'd say you can check if it's already a jQuery object using `instanceof jQuery`

Comment: Your question isn't precise enough but `$(jqueryObject)` goes through [`makeArray`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/core.js#L300) which is far from being just a simple test. I personally try to avoid such a case when performances may matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, since I seem to never be able to walk away from a Yak that needs shaving, here's the [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquerying-a-jquery-object), which seems to suggest that checking and short-circuiting instead of (accidentally) re-wrapping a jQuery instance can improve performance by up to 30%. In my books, that's significant enough to warrant the uglier code.

Here are the two tests:

```
function noCheck(element) {
  var $element = $(element);

  $element.css("color", "red");
}

noCheck($("#somediv"));

function shortCircuit(element) {
  var $element = element instanceof jQuery ? element : $(element);

  $element.css("color", "red");
}

shortCircuit($("#somediv"));
```

According to JSPerf, `noCheck` performs 30% slower than `shortCircuit`

Play around with this code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dmcfLgy/).

*I'm not going to accept my answer for a while to encourage additional perspectives / tests, etc.*

Comment: Cool test, but I have a question. If jQuery function really is using makeArray for everything that is "not a string, a DOM element or a function," then how come `$($('body')) instanceof Array` returns false but `$.makeArray($('body')) instanceof Array` returns true? I'm just curious and sorry if I'm missing something important.

Comment: @Shashank sounds like that should be another SE question! I got bogged down once I got into `makeArray()`, hence the reason I posted the original question! :)

Comment: I was kind of hoping you could answer seeing as how you've already looked at the jquery source, and my question is based on the premise that what you said is true (I haven't perused the source myself), but nvm. I'll add this task to my callback queue.

Comment: 30% isn't enough to optimize for with >90% of webapps. And the reason jQuery doesn't do it by default is probably so a "broken" jquery object is replaced with a fresh one.

Comment: @slicedtoad that's an interesting perspective. What's a "broken" jQuery object, how does it get that way and how does re-wrapping it fix it (based on the source code)?

Comment: @TomAuger I was just guessing, but I tested it and it works. I'll add an actual answer.

Comment: @TomAuger, nvm. It fixes some things, like if you do `$().prevObject = 3` wrapping it will remove `prevObject` completely. But it won't recreate `$().selector`, so I don't think it's really meant to be used to unbreak jquery objects.